# How to check if an argument is a tuple or array literal in ESLint?

Tags: typescript, eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-eslint

I am trying to create a lint rule to raise an error when the argument to a function call is not an array literal or a tuple.

Valid cases

```
test([]) // Case 1
test([1, 2, 3]) // Case 2

const a = [1, 2] as const // Case 3
test(a)

const a: [number, number] = [1, 2] // Case 4
test(a)
```

Invalid cases

```
const a = [1, 2]
test(a)

const b = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    b.push(i)
}
test(b)
```

My current code

```
CallExpression: (node: TSESTree.CallExpression) => {
  // check if the function name matches
  // ...
  
  const argument = node.arguments[0]


  if (argument.type === "ArrayExpression") {
    console.log("skip since it's array expression")
    return
  }

  context.report({
    node: argument,
    message: //....
  })
}
```

Unfortunately this would only work for Case 1 and 2. How to make it work for case 3 and 4